# How I created objects of an abstract class?

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

1. Why `GeometricObject[] abstractObjects = new GeometricObject[10];` don't cause error that I create objects of an abstract class?
2. What's the difference between `A[] objects;` and `A[] objects = new A[7];`

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[8];
        A[] objects = new A[7];
        GeometricObject[] abstractObjects = new GeometricObject[10];
        System.out.println(numbers[3]); // prints 0
        System.out.println(objects[4]); // prints null
        System.out.println(abstractObjects[6]); // prints null
    }
}

abstract class GeometricObject {}

class A
{
    public int number;
    A()
    {
        number = 13;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 GeometricObject[] abstractObjects = new GeometricObject[10];
```

you are not creating object of GeometricObject here.
You are creating an object of an array(of type `GeometricObject class`).

> What's the difference between A[] objects; and A[] objects = new
> A[7];

`A[] objects = new A[2]` is divided in two parts

`A[] objects` - its called deceleration of object.

`new A[7]` - called initialization of object